# rename output file using split function on mac osx

Tags: bash

I am trying to split a large file in a chunk of 16 lines in each output file. I can do that using `split -l 16 q1.txt new`. But I want the output to be like ratio1.txt, ratio2.txt, ......ratio100.txt etc. So I tried: `split -l 16 -d --additional-suffix=.txt q1.txt ratio`

Then I get this error message on my mac:

```
split: illegal option -- d
usage: split [-a sufflen] [-b byte_count] [-l line_count] [-p pattern]
             [file [prefix]]
```

Can anybody please help me to get the desired output file strings? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `man split` you'll find that the argument `--additional-suffix=SUFFIX` is not supported in this version.

To achieve what I understand you want you'll need an Automator script or a shell script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh

DONE=false
until $DONE; do
  for i in $(seq 1 16); do 
    read line || DONE=true;
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue;
    lines+=$line$'\n';
  done
  ratio=${lines::${#lines}-10}
  (cat "Ratio"; echo "$ratio .txt";)
  #echo "--- DONE SPLITTING ---";
  lines=;
done < $1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen man split, but couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: you can try this script like this:
`nano scriptname.sh` will open the editor, you paste the script, then `chmod a+x scriptname.sh` will make it executable, then invoke it with `./scriptname.sh q1.txt`